# Inline if sentence breaking rules in java formatting?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm new to java programming, and i'm wondering how i should do my if statements. As if i should always put my commands below the if statement, or can i just do it how I like it to be?

example:

```
int i = 5;
if (i == 5) System.out.println("i is 5");
```

or should i do it like this:

```
int i = 5;
if (i == 5)
    System.out.println("i is 5");
```

I understand if I've multiply lines of code to do, i would go for the last example above, but if i only have one command, wouldn't it be cleaner?

Comment: You're new and so I urge you to surround all if statements, and in fact all control statements in general, in curly braces. You don't know how many questions we see on this site from newbies who don't do this, then add another line below the first one, thinking that it too is controlled by the if statement, and formatted as if it were controlled by the statement -- but it's not. Don't shoot yourself in the foot accidentally at this stage of the game and use curly braces for all, even one line if blocks, for loops, etc..

Comment: Yeah. I use indentations as well.. Didn't figure how do display 'em in Stack overflow.. But even tho... would you use that much space for only one command?

Comment: Yes you would. The key is in preventing errors. It's a whole lot easier preventing them than debugging them. Later as you get more adept in programming, then sure, skip the curly braces if you want, but not now.

Comment: If you want to follow the Java Code Conventions then you will always use braces even for single liners the same way like for multiple lines inside the block.

Comment: Ah, okay.. So you would do it like this ?

if (i == 5) {
System.out.println("i is 5");
}

Comment: Yes, but as 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple lines to do you need to use the curly braces `{}` to denote new code block!

In your example both approaches are valid and would do the same thing, but it's a good practice to always use curly brackets as

```
int i = 5;
if (i == 5) {
    System.out.println("i is 5");
}
```

because it is easier to read and also less error prone when modifying the code later on. One should always try to make code easy to read.

note that

```
if (i == 5)


System.out.println("i is 5");
```

will do the same thing, but one might miss that the last line gets executed only when the condition holds true.

Comment: Even more risky is the case when someone comments out the println and does not see the corresponding if. Then the next statement to println is suddenly unexpected inside the if. I had this error a few year ago. I won't never ever use if statements without braces again.

Comment: So you would, even tho it take up 3 lines? I see that curly brackets can be useful, but when you combine the if statement and the command at the same line, I don't think you would see that different, and it would save up some room..?

Comment: It depends on your coding conventions in your team. Personally I don't like to put `} else {` in one line but that's the common convention and I do it. For me it's part of being professional to follow the code conventions you acknowledged and to resist personal preferences.

Comment: @user3010171 the benefit saving lines is small compared to possible problems later on when you modify the code and it breaks. (this does happen). Also what if the command is too long and doe snot fit well on one line with the if, or what if the if clause is long? Do you want to decide for every if you write, how to write it? It is better to focus on the important parts and keep standards in formatting....

Comment: Okay, Thanks for helping me out with this :-)